# How to make code work with try-catch? BMI Exceptions

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I can't seem to get try catch to work in my code. I am very new to this, and I have to use it. I need the user to enter input, and then I need to check that input, probably in a loop, for errors, to be caught by the exception.

-Perform input validation by making sure that the user enters a positive integer number for feet, a nonnegative decimal number for inches, and a positive decimal number for weight.

-Additionally, constrain the range of values entered to a logical range for each value.  For example, when entering height in feet, a fairly reasonable range would include values from 4-7.  Constrain inches and weight in a similar manner.

Any help would be much appreciated! I feel like I'm asking for a lot, but I've been stuck on this for weeks :/

As you can see in my code I have tried things, like a while loop with the try catch and exceptions.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    double weight = 0; //positive decimal number
    int heightFeet = 0; //positive int number for feet
    double heightIn = 0;//nonnegative decimal number for inches
    double BMI;

    System.out.print("Enter height using feet space inches (e.g., 5 6.25): ");
    while(true){
        try {
            heightFeet = Integer.parseInt(in.next());
            heightIn = Double.parseDouble(in.next());
            break;
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Invalid feet value. Must be an integer.");
            System.out.println("Invalid inches value. Must be a decimal number.");
            System.out.print("Re-enter height using feet space inches (e.g., 5 6.25): ");
        }
    }//end while


    System.out.print("Enter weight in pounds: ");
    while(true){
        try {
            weight = Double.parseDouble(in.next());
            break;
        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            System.out.println("Invalid pounds value. Must be positive.");
            System.out.println("Re-enter weight in pounds: ");
        }
    }//end while


    final int bmi = 704;
    double heightNew = (heightFeet * 12) + heightIn;

    BMI = Math.round(((weight * bmi) / (heightNew * heightNew))); //BMI
    //needs to round up, not down

    //constrain range of values able to be entered
    //feet should be 4-7
    //inches and weight similar

    //end print result
    System.out.println("\nheight = " + heightFeet + "'-" + heightIn + "\"");
    System.out.println("weight = " + weight + " pounds");
    System.out.print("body mass index = " + BMI);

    in.close();
}//end main
```

Output should look like this:

Enter height using feet space inches (e.g., 5 6.25): hi there

Invalid feet value. Must be an integer.

Invalid inches value. Must be a decimal number.

Re-enter height using feet space inches (e.g., 5 6.25): 0 9

Invalid feet value. Must be positive.

Re-enter height using feet space inches (e.g., 5 6.25): 5.25 0

Invalid feet value. Must be an integer.

Re-enter height using feet space inches (e.g., 5 6.25): 5 9.25

Enter weight in pounds: 0

Invalid pounds value. Must be positive.

Re-enter weight in pounds: 150.5

height = 5'-9.25"

weight = 150.5 pounds

body mass index = 22.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bet you feel as though you're so close you can taste it ... and you are. Things to consider:

Let's start with the `"Enter height using feet space inches (e.g., 5 6.25): "` prompt. I personally am not a firm believer in the `while (true) {` condition. It can be used of course but people tend to get in the habit of using it all the time and there will come a time when the practice will bite and produce a headache. Since you need to meet certain constraints with all the input anyways it wouldn't hurt to utilize a boolean flag whereas if all input has passed constraints then the **while** loop is exited, for example:

```
boolean pass = false;
while (!pass) {
    /* .... Your Prompt Code .... */
}

pass = false;
while (!pass) {
    /* .... Your Other Prompt Code .... */
}
```

For the **heightFeet** variable:

Obviously, if anything other than an Integer value is supplied for the token spot where feet is to be provided (the first supplied value before the supplied whitespace), a **NumberFormatException** will be thrown and caught (this would include a numerical value that contains a decimal point). Your message to console is displayed indicating as such and the User can try again, this is good. But if the token spot contains a value **less than** `4` or a value **greater than** `7` the the variable is filled with that value and the **heightIn** variable is worked on next. So far so good **but** keep in mind that you don't want values less than 4 or greater than 7.

For the **heightIn** variable:

If the next token spot (the second supplied value after the supplied whitespace) is anything other than a Integer or Double numerical value then again, a **NumberFormatException** will be thrown and caught and again your message to console is displayed indicating as such and the User can try again, this too is good. But if that token spot contains a numerical value that is **less than** 0.0 (or 0) or **greater than** 11.99 then, yes.... that value will be added to the **heightIn** variable. That's okay too but now is the time to enforce the desired constraints before moving onward. You want to check the values contained within the **heightFeet** and **heightIn** variables to ensure they meet the necessary criteria ***before*** getting out of the **`while`** loop.

This is where you would use one or more **if** statements so as to check the condition of each variable and ensure they meet constraints.

```
/* Is feet greater than 3 and less than 8 (4 to 7) and 
   is inches 0 or greater and less than 12   */
If (heightFeet > 3 && heightFeet < 8 && heightIn >= 0.0d && heightIn <= 11.9375d) {
    // All is Good!
    pass = true;    // set to true so as to exit the while loop.
}
else {
    // Hmmm....something's not right.
    System.out.println("The height supplied (" + hightFeet + " " + 
             heightIn + ") is invalid! Try again:");
}
```

Of course you would get rid of the **`break;`** statement, it's no longer needed.

Why use `<= 11.9375d` as part of a condition of the **heightIn** variable? There are 12 inches to a foot so anything over 11-15/16 inches can be considered a 1 foot. Mind you, I don't think anyone measures a person to the 16th of an inch but just in case they do. This can of course be reduced even more to say 11.75 (11 and 3 guarter's of an inch) if you like.

Now the `"Enter weight in pounds: "` prompt:

Try to use the similar concept as was done for the previous prompt :)

Comment: Thank you so much! This is an amazing answer and helped me out tremendously! Now my code works beautifully without any errors. You are great! Also thank you for such a long and detailed answer~